# Specific element in a List Java

Tags: java, list, methods

So I want to output the max PRICE of a List.[image: My method who finds the max Price]

Now I need the i-1 element of the for loop to get the index and then print it as a List
how should it be ?
[image]

I have some exprience in C# where I think this works there but in Java it doesnt. :/

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - That being said, you seem to know that you access a List element with the method `BookList1.get(i)` because you do that inside your loop, why do you suddenly decide to try `BookList1[i-1]` a few lines later? The second version is simply not how Lists work in java.

Comment: Why do you think you need the `i-1`th element? That will always be the last element of the list. Just print `max`. Also, no need for `i` and `b = BookList1.get(i)` at all; with that loop, `b` already is the book.

Comment: I would suggest to look at the `Streaming Api` in java.

Comment: Use `Collections.max(BookList1, Comparator.comparing(book -> book.getPrice());`... Which gives you what you want in 1 line.

Comment: Also put your code in your quetsion with ``` at the start and at the end in a seperate line. This will format your text as code.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support overwriting operators, so `BookList1[i-1]` is not allowed, because `BookList1` is not an array. You need to use `BookList1.get(i-1)` to get the element on that index. In C# you are allowed to use `BookList1[i]`, because C# lists implement this operator. This was already introduced in C++, but never im Java.

Comment: Thanks man. That's something I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach to print most expensive:

```
public void getMostExpensive (List<Book> bookList){
    Book expensive = bookList.get(0);
    for (Book book : bookList) {
            if(book.getPrice() > expensive.getPrice())
                expensive = book;
    }
    System.out.println(expensive.getPrice());
}
```